# How to format the date

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, datetime-format

Below function `sendMail()` running fine.  the email generated showing date in format `Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)` but i only want to display it as `Fri May 29 2020` or `May 29 2020` on email generated e.g for var `INVOICE_DATE` which is picking date from a cell where it is displayed as 
`11/30/2019`

```
  function sendMail() {
  var CUSTOMER_NAME = 0;
  var SALESPERSON = 1;
  var INVOICE_DATE = 2;   
  var PAYMENT_TERMS = 3;
  var INVOICE_AMOUNT = 4;
  var NOT_YET_DUE_AMOUNT = 5;
  var TOTAL_OVER_DUE_AMOUNT = 6;
  var TIME_LEFT_OVERDUE_NOTIFICATION = 7;
  var DEFULT_DATE = 8;
  var NOTIFICATION_DATE = 9;
  var CLAIM_DATE = 10;
  var EMAIL = 11;
  var copyTo = 12;
  var attachments = 13;
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");  
  var ws = 
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Notification 
     Alert");
  var wsSettings = 
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings");

  var name = wsSettings.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var subject = wsSettings.getRange("G3").getValue();
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:O" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[14] == true});
  data.forEach(function(row){

  emailTemp.Cn = row[CUSTOMER_NAME];
  emailTemp.Sp = row[SALESPERSON];
  emailTemp.Im = row[INVOICE_DATE];
  emailTemp.Pt = row[PAYMENT_TERMS];
  emailTemp.Ia = row[INVOICE_AMOUNT];
  emailTemp.Ntdue = row[NOT_YET_DUE_AMOUNT];
  emailTemp.Ovrdue = row[TOTAL_OVER_DUE_AMOUNT];
  emailTemp.TleftOvrdueN = row[TIME_LEFT_OVERDUE_NOTIFICATION];
  emailTemp.Dd = row[DEFULT_DATE];
  emailTemp.Notidate = row[NOTIFICATION_DATE];
  emailTemp.Cdate = row[CLAIM_DATE];

  var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(row[EMAIL],
      subject,
      "Your email does not support HTML.",
                       {name: name, htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: "xyz@gmail.com", cc: row[copyTo]}
    );

    });

 }
```

Comment: Try using `getDisplayValues()`; or use `Utilities.formatDate()`

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Cooper Can you please guide me where and how i can add this  getDisplayValues(); or Utilities.formatDate(). i am new to this and above code just code

Comment: Just read the documentation and try it yourself.  If you need further assistance return with another question.

Answer (score 0):

**[toDateString](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/)** method for Date object is what you need.

```
var str = "Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)";
var time = new Date(str);

console.log(time.toDateString()); //"Fri May 29 2020"
```